# If $x$ is random uniform in $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$, $y$ a quadratic non-residue with Jacobi symbol 1, then $x^2y$ is a random QNR with Jacobi 1

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-distributions, quadratic-residues

I've encountered the following claim in a paper I'm reading:

> If $x$ is random uniform in $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$, and $y$ is an arbitrary
> quadratic non-residue with Jacobi symbol +1, then $x^2y$ is a random uniform
> quadratic non-residue with Jacobi symbol +1.

Note that $N=pq$ where $p,q$ are two primes $>2$.

I'm unable to see why this is true (probability is not my strongest suit, so I'm not entirely sure even how one would go about showing something is random uniform if not through directly computing, e.g., $\Pr[X^2y=a]$ for some $a$ in quadratic non-residue with Jacobi +1 and showing it's exactly 1 out of the size of the set).

What am I missing? Perhaps showing there's a bijection between $X^2y$ and NQRs with Jacobi 1?

Comment: This is not true in general if $y$ is supposed to be fixed. For instance, suppose $n=3\cdot5\cdot7$ and $y=-1$; then $x^2y$ is distributed uniformly among those elements which are nonresidues mod $3$ and $7$ but residues mod $5$, which is a proper subset of all nonresidues mod $3\cdot5\cdot7$ with Jacobi symbol $1$ (e.g. $x^2y=8$ cannot happen). It is true that $x^2y$ is uniformly distributed, just not among *all* QNRs with JS=1.

Comment: @runway44 Perhaps I misunderstood the statement and they meant that $y$ is not fixed..? Also, $N=pq$ (two primes), if that matters. Adding this to the original question.

Comment: Yes, $n=pq$ being a semiprime definitely matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is drawn uniformly from a finite set, and $f$ is an $n$-to-$1$ map from that set to another, then $f(X)$ is drawn uniformly from the range of $f$. Note that $x\mapsto x^2$ is such a map $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times\to(\mathbb{Z}_n^\times)^2$.

What about the map $x^2\mapsto x^2 y$? This is where it's important $n=pq$ is a semiprime. Then by CRT we can say $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times=\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\times\mathbb{Z}_q^\times$. The pairs of Legendre symbols mod $p$ and $q$ are $(1,1)$ for QRs, are $(-1,-1)$ for QNRs with JS $=1$, and are $(+1,-1)$ or $(-1,+1)$ for QNRs with JS $=-1$. Thus, the QRs are an index two subgroup of the residues JS $=1$, hence multiplying by $y$ (an element of the nontrivial coset) is a bijection between the QRs and the QNRs with JS=1.

Comment: How would you prove the first claim (first two sentences)? Again a bijection claim? (sorry if it's trivial, I really do want to understand these type of proofs properly). Also, if you don't mind clarifying -- how do you show that the QRs are (a) a subgroup and (b) of index 2?

Comment: @Anon It should be intuitively obvious, no? Anyway, if $f:A\to B$ is an $m$-to-$1$ mapping, and $X$ is drawn uniformly from $A$, then the probability $f(X)$ equals a particular element $b\in B$ equals the sum of $1/|A|$ over all $X$ in the fiber $f^{-1}(b)$, which eqals $m/|A|=1/|B|$.

Comment: And, (a) QRs are a subgroup because closed under identity, inverses, multiplication, and (b) the QRs have index two in the group of residues with JS=1 because e.g. it is the kernel of the Legendre symbol (mod one of $p$ or $q$; they match). Or you could actually show multiplying by $y$ is a bijection between this subgroup and its complement, which is kind of the reverse of what I said in this answer but whatever.